# Chain accessors or return the value of private pointer

Tags: object-oriented, c++, encapsulation

I am having trouble thinking through what best-practice dictate I do in this situation.

Say I have the following class structure

```
Class A {
public:
    bool isCompressed() { return compressed_; }
private:
    bool compressed_;
}

Class B {
private:
    ClassA *a_ptr_;
public:
    /* Accessor here */
}
```

If I needed to get access to the `compressed_` variable in `ClassA` within an implementation having a `ClassB` object should I have an accessor like this:

```
ClassA* ClassB::filePointer() const {
    return a_ptr_;
}
```

and implementation of

```
if (objectA.filePointer()->isCompressed()) { ... }
```

or this:

```
bool ClassB::isFileCompressed() const { 
    return a_ptr_->isCompressed(); 
}
```

and implementation of

```
if (objectB.isFileCompressed()) { ... }
```

I realize this might be a bit of a best-practice question (or maybe it isn't...?) but hopefully can tell me which way one should be going about this!

Comment: The former overexposes the implementation details of class b,  so the latter is better from that regard.

Comment: Check law of demeter, it pretty much answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is returning a private pointer is a bad idea ?**

By making a member private, you express that this is the class internal business, and that you want to ave the freedom to manage such interals as you want.

The problem when returning a private pointer, you give your control away, breaking your own design intention:

- What happens if the caller deletes the pointer, accidentally thinking that it was a pointer to copy for his own use ?
- What happens if the caller invokes members of the pointed object that alter its state (e.g. close the file, while your B class assumes it remains open) ?
- What happens if the caller stores a copy of the pointer and uses it later ?  Especially if you have deleted the object in the meantime ?

You may hope that adding the const keyword avoids these problems.  Unfortunately `A* B::filePointer() const {...}` just means that this member function doesn't change the state of B object.

You could mitigate a little bit the risks, by making it `const A* B::filePointer() const {...}`. In this way, the caller could only invoke const member functions on the file pointer, and assign it co a pointer to const.  Unfortunately, this will not prevent accidental deletion.

[Online demo of the issue](http://ideone.com/mVyUyg)

The other drawback is that consumers of class B depend also on the internals of that class.  This doesn't respect the principle of .

**Encapsulation and separation of concerns**

Your "Chained accessor" alternative looks much better:

- it uses [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) effectively to hide the implementation details completely.  If tomorrow you prefer to use a stream instead of a class A, you can do it: the world outside class B doesn't have to know anything about your change.
- it promotes [separation of concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/) : the class B doesn't have to know anything about the internals of class A, because it only uses a public member.  And the outside world doesn't have to know anything about class B internals, and thus doesn't depend on class A.